# Python TypeError must be str not int

Tags: python, python-3.6, typeerror

I am having trouble with the following piece of code:

```
    if verb == "stoke":

        if items["furnace"] >= 1:
            print("going to stoke the furnace")

            if items["coal"] >= 1:
                print("successful!")
                temperature += 250 
                print("the furnace is now " + (temperature) + "degrees!")
                           ^this line is where the issue is occuring
            else:
                print("you can't")

        else:
            print("you have nothing to stoke")
```

The resulting error comes up as the following:

```
    Traceback(most recent call last):
       File "C:\Users\User\Documents\Python\smelting game 0.3.1 build 
       incomplete.py"
     , line 227, in <module>
         print("the furnace is now " + (temperature) + "degrees!")
    TypeError: must be str, not int
```

I am unsure what the problem is as i have changed the name from temp to temperature and added the brackets around temperature but still the error occurs.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

`print("the furnace is now " + str(temperature) + "degrees!")`

cast it to `str`

Comment: Thanks, that worked

Comment: please accept the answer :)

Comment: Why is this the case? Why doesn't it just call int's __str__()  magic method and convert it before embedding into the string?

Comment: @Danil not particularly sure - i'll have to dig in to that

Comment: @Danil python does not usually automatically coerce things ("Explicit is better than implicit" - Zen of Python), when using the string's concatenate operator `+` it expects 2 strings and will fail if it doesn't get 2 strings. Note: `print()` takes multiple arguments and automatically calls `__str__()` on those arguments which is why you can do, `print("the furnace is now ", temperature, "degrees!")` without the explicit conversion.

Answer (score 18):

Python comes with numerous ways of formatting strings:

New style `.format()`, which supports a rich formatting mini-language:

```
>>> temperature = 10
>>> print("the furnace is now {} degrees!".format(temperature))
the furnace is now 10 degrees!
```

Old style `%` format specifier:

```
>>> print("the furnace is now %d degrees!" % temperature)
the furnace is now 10 degrees!
```

In Py 3.6 using the new `f""` format strings:

```
>>> print(f"the furnace is now {temperature} degrees!")
the furnace is now 10 degrees!
```

Or using `print()`s default `sep`arator:

```
>>> print("the furnace is now", temperature, "degrees!")
the furnace is now 10 degrees!
```

And least effectively, construct a new string by casting it to a `str()` and concatenating:

```
>>> print("the furnace is now " + str(temperature) + " degrees!")
the furnace is now 10 degrees!
```

Or `join()`ing it:

```
>>> print(' '.join(["the furnace is now", str(temperature), "degrees!"]))
the furnace is now 10 degrees!
```

Answer (score 7):

you need to cast int to str before concatenating. for that use `str(temperature)`. Or you can print the same output using `,` if you don't want to convert like this.

```
print("the furnace is now",temperature , "degrees!")
```