# Openpyxl iter_rows(min_row,max_row) with loop

Tags: python, excel, loops, row, openpyxl

Why is `iter_rows` always saying `must be str, not int`? I am simply trying to pass my `lst` values to `min_row` and `max_row`.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from itertools import islice

wb = load_workbook('xyz.xlsx')
ws1 = wb['Sheet1']

lst = ['2','2']
limit = 2

for i in islice(lst,limit):
    row = ws1.iter_rows(min_row=i,max_row=i)
```

I've tried casting ideas found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44916749/8099148) to `iter_rows` `min_row` `max_row` but, I just get the same error and `Worksheet object has no attribute`

Trackback error is

```
 line 509, in iter_rows
 max_row += row_offset
```

Comment: er, what do you want to do here? Why `itertools`? Add a print statement to see what you're actually trying to pass to `ws.iter_rows()`

Comment: I add print(i) to above for statement before and it prints 2 then same Traceback error. I add print(i) after for statement and it prints nothing and gives same TraceBack error.  I am trying to end up with min_row=2, max_row=2.  print(ws1.iter_rows) gives <bound method Worksheet.iter_rows of <Worksheet "Sheet1">> I hope this makes more sense and thanks for your inquiry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `iter_rows` method expects that the `min_row` and `max_row` input parameters are integers. So try this:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

from itertools import islice

wb = load_workbook('xyz.xlsx')
ws1 = wb['Sheet1']

lst = [2,2]
limit = 2

for i in islice(lst,limit):
    row = ws1.iter_rows(min_row=i,max_row=i)
```

**Note**: you can get the complete usage instructions for the `iter_rows` method by querying its docstring with command `help(ws1.iter_rows)` or `help(openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.Worksheet.iter_rows)`. Within the docstring you can find the instructions:

```
:param min_row: smallest row index (1-based index)
:type min_row: int

:param max_row: smallest row index (1-based index)
:type max_row: int
```

Comment: Thanks for help, but if you run your code it still gives error `must be str, not int`. It sounds counter to what the documentation mentions, but nonetheless that's what the interpreter throws. If you put a number in `min_row` and `max_row`  explicitly it will work, but something about using a `list` I'm having trouble on.

Comment: I tested this again and it worked when I printed i. However, in my program still some issues despite trying this. I will investigate more and thank you for your contribution and help to my issue.

Comment: @SpaceCadet The error message `must be str, not int` that is generated by the `iter_rows` method code line `max_row += row_offset` is a reference to the `row_offset` variable and *not* the `max_row` variable. Basically what happens is that python runs into trouble because it's being forced to add an integer object (`row_offset`) to a string object (`max_row`). The Python error handler then makes the assumption that the intention for the code line was to do a string addition operation, hence this error message.