# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '' using cookies in Flask application

Tags: python, flask, python-3.6, typeerror, valueerror

**Code For Retrieving Count of visiting website**

facing issue while retrieving the count value from `cookies.get()` method. Though I have tried to make use of typecasting as

```
count=int(request.cookies.get('cou',0))
```

getting `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''`.

```
from flask import Flask,request,make_response


app=Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/set/')
def s():

    msg='successfully set the cookie'
    res=make_response(msg)
    res.set_cookie('cou')
    return res


@app.route('/get/')
def g():
    count=request.cookies.get('cou',0)
    count+=1
    return 'visited this {} times'.format(str(count))

if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1',port=8000)
```

**Output:**

```
 return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "main.py", line 18, in g
    count+=1
TypeError: must be str, not int
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Jan/2021 22:08:56] "GET /get/ HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

I'm using Python 3.6.8.

Comment: Your title is showing only part of the error message, you also repeat this in the text. Why do you stop where it gets interesting? Both, Python3 and Python2.7 show ***what*** could not be evaluated to `int`. Would you please show us the complete error message? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What python version did you use?

Comment: Python-3.6.8 #wolf

Comment: Does my answer help in any way?

Comment: I have tried your solution @Wolf but the count value is not incrementing on visiting same site. Im getting "Visited 1 times " but it should print "visited {no_of_times_I_visited_the_site} times". Could you help me

Comment: What you still forget is to write the updated value back,`count` itself is just an `int`. There is no magic write if you increment it, so the cookie you stored once keeps its original value `0` and what you are displaying is this value plus one.

Comment: See updated answer! BTW: Does my last update to your question add the correct details?

Comment: I have used your way, which was used to bypass the Error. But could you tell me how to pass the count as a dynamic variable which gets incrimented while user refresh the website

Answer (score 1):

### Low-carb introduction

If you enter `int('')` in python console:

```py
>>> int('')
```

you will observe a “result” like this:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#10>", line 1, in <module>
    int('')
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Even if you don't know the actual code, you can guess which function call caused this. In other words, for error analysis it really pays to read the error messages carefully (and to the end).

### Feast with cookies

The problem you are facing is that the value returned by `request.cookies.get('cou', 0)` in fact *is* of type `str`. It's `''` and therefore cannot be converted into a valid base-10 `int`, the *`default`* you pass to [dict.get(key[, default])](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) has no effect for the lookup since the key `cou` has been found.

You actually set the cookie to the value `''` by implicitly using the default argument<sup>[1]</sup> of the parameter `value` of the [response.set_cookie(key, **value=''**,[...])](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/?highlight=set_cookie#flask.Response.set_cookie)

By replacing `res.set_cookie('cou')` with `res.set_cookie('cou', 0)`, you will leave the described problem behind.

Further reading:

- [Get and set cookies with Flask - Python Tutorial](https://pythonbasics.org/flask-cookies/#Create-cookie)
- [http.cookies — HTTP state management — Python 3.9.1 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.cookies.html?highlight=cookies#module-http.cookies)

### Problem shown in Output

This may duplicate the problem shown in [Python TypeError must be str not int](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44916637/2932052) and tells me that you are using some before Python 3.7. It's basically that you read the empty string (as mentioned) above and try to concatenate an integer to it. Since Python does not provide an automatic cast for here (because of the ambiguity between `s+str(1)` and `int(s)+1`) it refuses to execute the operation via

```
TypeError: must be str, not int
```

in Python 3.6 or, in Python 3.7+ via

```
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

---

<sup>[1]</sup> See the Python3 documentation, [*6.3.4. Calls*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#calls):

> "When all arguments have been processed, the **slots that are** still **unfilled are filled with the corresponding default value from the function definition.**"

### Update pending

<sup>a hint out of the scope of the actual question</sup>

What you still forget is to write the updated value back, `count` itself is just an `int`. There is no magic connected with incrementing it, so the cookie you stored once keeps its original value (`0`) and what you are displaying is that value plus one.